# Service Loader Class In Java, Having Issue with META-INF/services folder

Tags: java, service, loader, serviceloader

I'm stuck in service loader class(java) can anybody help, here is my code and pic attached with it.
see the pic to understand completely and tell me what's the issue

**Interface Code**

```java
package ServiceLoader_.SL;

interface Account {
    String getMessage();
}
```

**Class implementing that interface**

```java
package ServiceLoader_.SL;

public class Message implements Account {

    @Override
    public String getMessage() { 
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```java
package ServiceLoader_.SL;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLoader<Account> ac = ServiceLoader.load(Account.class);
        Account ab = ac.iterator().next();
        if(ac.iterator().hasNext()){
            System.out.println("hay^");
        }
    }
}
```

***Gives error that no such element found when trying to access ac.iterator().next()***

***Click*** [*Here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PmHB.png)**To See Image**

Comment: `META-INF` must reside at the classpath root, hence it must be a sibling of `ServiceLoader_`.

Comment: The general way to use an `Iterator`, is to call `hasNext()` *before* `next()`. And on the same iterator, instead of calling `iterator()` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by the documentation of [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html), the *provider-configuration file* must be part of the classpath and for `ServiceLoader<Account>` will be resolved as

```
META-INF/services/ServiceLoader_.SL.Account
```

Based on what I can deduct from the image, your file seems to reside at

```
ServiceLoader_/META-INF/services/ServiceLoader_.SL.Account
```

which the `ServiceLoader` implementation is unaware of, thus it will not locate (and therefore not provide) the implementation class `ServiceLoader_.SL.Message`.

To fix this issue you must move the `META-INF` to the classpath root. Since I do not recognize the IDE shown in the image, I cannot say how one can do that though.

Comment: Problem was that I didn't set the META-INF as Resources, after doing that It's working perfectly. Thanks for the suggestions.